# Disabled submenu in SystemTrayIcon for macOS (Qt 5.9.1)

Tags: macos, qt, qml

I would like to provide a basic system tray menu for my application on macOS. Basically it works fine, but my submenu is disabled no matter what.
I already tried to enable it by using the "enabled" property but this also had no effect.

Could you please provide a solution for this?

[This](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-platform-systemtrayicon.html) is the QML type I wanna use.

[Screenshot of the system tray menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHK0G.png)

Here's my QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import Qt.labs.platform 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("TestApplication")

    SystemTrayIcon {
        id: systemTrayIcon
        visible: true
        iconSource: "qrc:/images/icon_systray.png"

        menu: Menu {
            enabled: true
            Menu {
                id: submenu
                enabled: true
                title: "Select port"
                MenuItem {
                    enabled: true
                    text: "test1"
                    id: element1
                    onTriggered: Qt.quit()
                }
                MenuItem {
                    enabled: true
                    text: "test2"
                    id: element2
                    onTriggered: Qt.quit()
                }
            }
            MenuSeparator { }
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Connect")
                onTriggered: serCom.toggleSerialPortStatus()
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Quit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit()
            }
        }
    }
}
```